# How can I see the nslogs that my app does when It's archived as ad-hoc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I have an app which I archive it for Ad-hoc.
This app has nslogs in the code and I'd like to see them after run the app in my ipad.
For example, when I get a crash, I'd like to see the nslogs of my app to see any problem, and I don't know how to do it.
Thank you

Comment: is anything still unclear? :)

Comment: sorry, I forgot it. Marked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 6, go to  **Window --> Devices**, select your device in the **DEVICES** section on the left. Then click **View Device Logs**.

**Window --> Devices**
[image]

**Select device and see logs**
[image]

Comment: Hi, I do that but I just see the crash logs, not the "normal" logs

Comment: hmm normally they should be shown too... you're sure to use `NSLog()` not some custom logger?

Comment: yep, when I try the app with the simulator or the ipad connected, I see the nslogs in the console, but if I archive and install it, I'm not able to see them

Comment: maybe a logger is used that doesnt log in production builds? did you write the code by yourself?

Comment: It's a cordova app, but I wrote code in objective-c for a plugin, and this code has the nslogs

Comment: hmm that's strange... maybe you should go out and look for people who have similar issues using phonegap. the way i described works for regular iOS builds.

Comment: I'll do it. I'll wait to mark your answer, in case somebody does it. If now, I'll mark yours. Thank you anyway